# Overlay Blending Mode in Python Efficiently as Possible (Numpy, OpenCV)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

Suppose I have two numpy image arrays, `a` and `b`, of the same dimensions, 8-bit color, RGB format.  Now suppose I want to produce a new numpy array whose pixel values are that of the previous two combined using the "Overlay" blending mode.

Its definition, as taken from Wikipedia, is as follows, where `b` is the top layer and `a` is the bottom layer:

[image]

In the formula, I believe `a` and `b` are represented in terms of their "whiteness" in the sense that a completely white pixel is 1 and a completely black pixel is 0.  I am not sure how hue plays into that.

I'm not sure if there's a faster way to do this other than by iterating over the two images pixel by pixel, which is REALLY slow for 1920x1080 images.  I need to be able to do this as fast as possible.

For example, I managed to implement the Addition blending mode as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

a = cv2.imread("a.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
b = cv2.imread("b.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

a = a.astype(float)
b = b.astype(float)

ab = a
for i in range(len(ab)):
  ab[i] = a[i] + b[i]

cv2.imwrite('Out.png', ab)
```

It seems to be pretty fast, and is certainly much faster than attempting to achieve the same thing by iterating pixel by pixel.  But once again, this is just the Addition blending mode, and I need the Overlay blending mode.

**If you know of any Python implementation of the Overlay blending mode between two RGB images in the form of numpy arrays that is very efficient, please help me find it.  If not, can you implement it as efficiently as possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

a = cv2.imread("a.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
b = cv2.imread("b.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

a = a.astype(float)/255  
b = b.astype(float)/255 # make float on range 0-1

mask = a >= 0.5 # generate boolean mask of everywhere a > 0.5 
ab = np.zeros_like(a) # generate an output container for the blended image 

# now do the blending 
ab[~mask] = (2*a*b)[~mask] # 2ab everywhere a<0.5
ab[mask] = (1-2*(1-a)*(1-b))[mask] # else this
```

I think that should do it. Now `ab` is a float image on -1,2 and is a blend of `a` and `b`. This will be relatively fast because it utilizes `broadcasting` and `masking` instead of a loop. I'm curious to hear the speed difference.

---

Following material added by Mark Setchell 16-NOV-2018, just so you all know who the guilty party is :-)

The values calculated by Mr Kayaks' code are floats in the range 0..1, whereas `imwrite()` is expecting uint8s in the range 0..255. So you just need to add the following to the bottom of his code:

```
# Scale to range 0..255 and save
x=(ab*255).astype(np.uint8) 
cv2.imwrite('result.png',x)
```

If you then take these two images as `a.jpg` and `b.jpg`:

[image] [image]

You will get the result on the left - the one on the right is what you get from Photoshop if you choose **Overlay** blend mode:

[image] [image]

Comment: When I follow your code with the line `cv2.imwrite('zOutNEW.png', ab)`, the output image seems to be really dark, and is drastically different than the results you get in Photoshop.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: I suspect imwrite expects a uint8 on range 0-255. That's what I'd try first. Provided `ab.min()` is about -1 and `ab.max()` is about 1, try `ab = ((ab-ab.min())/2.0*255.0).astype('uint8')`. You may need an axis parameter in the `min`. I don't have python on this computer to check right now.

To debug, also try beforehand to replicate your previous additive blending result using masking and broadcasting. These principles are the way to do it fast.

Comment: Any update ? Your problem is probably imwrite's input datatype or my interpretation of a and b.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my adding a bit to your code - reject it or delete it if you do. I wanted to add it as you were so close but I didn't want to add a competing answer and steal the points you deserve. I hope you understand.